# Retrieving the Recommendations using Microsoft Graph Security API in Azure

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

I am able to retrieve Security Alerts using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/alerts?$top=1
```

Now I would like to retrieve the "recommendations" from an Azure tenant

We can see these recommendations in Azure portal -> Security Center -> Recommendations. We can see Recommendations blade under "RESOURCE SECURITY HYGIENE" tab.

Is it possible to retrieve Recommendations using Microsoft Graph? If so, can someone help me with correct URI to fetch them?

Comment: You use correct URL. You can test it on Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=security/alerts&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com . Could you please clarify what is the problem with calling it?

Comment: Hi Patutin Thanks for the quick reply. URL which i mentioned above is retrieving the Security Alerts  in Azure portal -> Security Center ->Security alerts. But I want similar API which will retrieve the recommendations in Azure portal -> Security Center -> Recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further digging into the Azure api docs. You can’t use the Graph API as said but by the looks of things you can use the [Resource Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/tasks/list) to list the recommendations as Tasks from the security center. Let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The resource manager API is returning lot of Tasks but it is not returning the recommendation under  Azure portal -> Security Center -> Recommendations

Comment: Ok that’s good to know. Thanks for letting me know they weren’t the same. They looked like they were. I’m not sure of a way to help then. Sorry

Comment: May be i checked this API rush at that time. Using this API i am able to retrieve the Security recommendations. That is why i am marking this as Answer. Thanks for the help Phil